# Display Specific Categories in Javascript Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to return a unique list of key value names in a javascript array.  I have only been able to specify the array index but I would like to return all the category names in the whole array.  I keep getting undefined.

This is what I have tried:

```
var Foods = {
    "Fruits": [
        {
        "id": "1",
        "Name": "Granny Smith",
        "Category": "Apple"},
        {
        "id": "2",
        "Name":"Raspberries",
        "Category": "Berries"}              
       ],

    "Potatoes": [
       {
       "id": "3",
       "Name":"Maris Piper",
       "Category": "White"}
       {
       "id": "4",
       "Name":"Charlotte",
       "Category": "Baby"}
   ]}

  for(var categories in Foods) {
  var cats = Foods[categories][1].Category;
  document.write(cats);
  }
```

Ideally I would like to be able to return:

Apple
Berries
Baby
White

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `Array#forEach` function inside your `for...in` loop. Then save it in e.g. array or basically log it.

```
for (let item in Foods) {
  Foods[item].forEach(v => console.log(v.Category));
}
```

Snippet:

```js
var Foods = {
  "Fruits": [{
      "id": "1",
      "Name": "Granny Smith",
      "Category": "Apple"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "Name": "Raspberries",
      "Category": "Berries"
    }
  ],
  "Potatoes": [{
    "id": "3",
    "Name": "Maris Piper",
    "Category": "White"
  }, {
    "id": "4",
    "Name": "Charlotte",
    "Category": "Baby"
  }]
}, names = [];

for (let item in Foods) {
  Foods[item].forEach(v => names.push(v.Category));
}

console.log(names);
```

Comment: That's awesome.  How could I make v.category = to a variable?

Comment: @Hexana You can e.g. push it to a new array. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Cracking.  Thanks a lot Kind user.

Answer (score 1):

You had `category` while it should be `Category` (before the edit)

You can also just use `reduce` and `Object.keys`

```
var cats = Object.keys(Foods).reduce((prev, next) => {
   prev = prev.concat(Foods[next].map(v => v.Category));
   return prev;
}, [])
```

Comment: Well spotted :)